# Data loss on shared folder on Google Drive (between pc syncs)

Tags: google-drive-api

I have two Computers connected to one folder on Google drive. The one PC **(A)** has not connected to Google Drive for a while. The other one **(B)** has been doing a lot of changes. Then suddenly PC **(A)** connected and synced up overwriting everything that PC **(B)** has been up to.

Is there a way to undo the changes made by **(A)** or to find deleted files made but **(A)**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a question best suited for superuser.com.

But, to answer your question, Drive has [Changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-changes) and [Revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-revisions) that helps check for any changes on a file. Its possible that the old revisions were already pruned and when PC A was suddenly connected and synced, it was treated as a new version and overwrote the file. I'm not sure as to how it can be stopped on the Drive application, but by if the file is on a Google Domain (Docs, Sheets, etc.), each file can be restored to a specific revision if you check the See Revision History.